# Update query take time even with index

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

I have the following UPDATE query

```
UPDATE Member 
SET Gem=Gem+1 
WHERE UserId='4200000' 
LIMIT 1
```

That table **Member** has 4,250,000 row and **UserId** is Index and about 62G. Right now, the query take time about 0 time, but problem start in peak time when about 2500 connection/process send this simple query take more time.

I search a lot and can't find anything. Server hard drive is `Nvme` and not busy and here top print:

> load average: 3.60, 3.26, 3.39 %Cpu(s): 22.2 us, 9.0 sy, 0.0 ni, 66.7 id, 0.5 wa, 0.0 hi, 1.6 si, 0.0 st KiB Mem : 61679480 total, 622156 free, 52283348 used, 8773976 buff/cache KiB Swap: 30932988 total, 11625264 free, 19307724 used. 8401896 avail Mem

CPU not invole and ram just get innodb_buffer_pool reserve 52G.

The only help I get was [LOCK SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html)
but not finding anything usefull.

As you see there is no problem in source, how can know what is problem with a simple index query take time in peak time?

Comment: You don't define "More Time". If you say it's taking 2sec, that isn't bad for 2500 connections. If you say 2min, that would be an issue. I don't know MySQL well, but it looks like there's a limit of 151 simultaneous client connections. You could try increasing max_connections

Comment: You can also try implementing "Connection Pooling" which will allow a single connection to be used my multiple threads.

Comment: Is your `UserId` _not_ an integer?

Comment: Does "62G" mean the member table is 62 Gigabyte big? That's quite big for a table with only 4,250,000 rows. That's over 150 Kilobyte per row. I would say that that is your problem.

Comment: @Robert Paulsen max connection is set 6500 and not a proble.

Comment: @Nae, yes it is integer

Comment: @KIKO Software, that is irrelevent, my problem query is for update an integer that is Gem that is a integer. 62 gig is about some other string for each member that only maybe use 1 time in a day and not a problem.

Comment: You may know this, but changing the max connections requites restarting MySQL.

Comment: @ Robert Paulsen, Thanks but i know that, and just for you to knowif max connection full there will error in php and connection lost, and not wait and get slow query.

Comment: I'd start by filtering integer, using _integer_. You're searching for integer with text. Then ensure normalization of the data, reducing the size the uncircumstantially same values occupy. Perhaps also consider partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Because your UserID is integer and INDEXED, this query

UPDATE Member 
SET Gem=Gem+1 
WHERE UserId='4200000' 
LIMIT 1

will perform better if you will remove the apostrophe's from around the
UserID data.  You are causing TEXT lookup rather than using INTeger data to 
find the row to modify.  Please post before and after timing during busy time.

What is your result of SELECT @@innodb_io_capacity;  what does manufacturer claim IOPS for write sequential using your NVME model?